# OAuth token does not exist - 401

Tags: php, oauth

I've been working on my following issue for a few hours now and it is driving me crazy.

We have a module developed by a third party which did work fine until now, this is used to connect to timetag and this way request calendars for our volunteers.

Using the manual given by this third party company there is a part on this error "401 - OAuth token does not exist"

They are saying to comment these lines:

```
//if (!$token) {
    $client->authenticate();
    $client->setToken(reformatToken($client->getToken()));
//} else {
//   $client->setToken($token);
//}
```

And then signout of google, surf to the component on the website, grant access and uncomment them again so that the token gets refreshed.
Doing this, however, makes no difference whatsoever and I still get the error shown above.

Is there anyone who can assist me in fixing this error so that our volunteers can again see their calendar and schedule?

Many thanks in advance already!

Full code of this page (omitting the CSS of course) is found below.

```
<?php
/*
 * OAuth and Timetag connection stuff:
 */
use Joomla\Registry\Registry;

$options = new Registry([
"clientid" => "MY_CLIENT_ID",
"clientsecret" => "MY_CLIENT_SECRET",
"authurl" => "https://timetag.it/api_oauth_authorize",
"redirecturi" => "WEBSITE_URL",
"scope" => "general",
"tokenurl" => "https://timetag.it/oauth/token",
"userefresh" => true,
"sendheaders" => true
    ]);

$client = new JOAuth2Client($options);

// Manually reformat the token, because the format received from Timetag is different than the one accepted by JOAuth2Client
function reformatToken($token) {
$newToken = json_decode(key($token), true);
$newToken["created"] = $newToken["created_at"];
unset($newToken["created_at"]);

return $newToken;
}

$db = JFactory::getDbo();

$dbTokenConditions = array(
$db->quoteName("user_id") . " = " . $db->quote(1), // Custom id
$db->quoteName("profile_key") . " = " . $db->quote("profile.timetag_token")     // Custom key
);

// Get token from database
$query = $db->getQuery(true);
$query->select("*")->from($db->quoteName("#__user_profiles"))->where($dbTokenConditions);
$result = $db->setQuery($query)->loadObject();
$token = json_decode($result->profile_value, true);

// Only authenticate when there's no token available
if (!$token) {
$client->authenticate();
$client->setToken(reformatToken($client->getToken()));
} else {
   $client->setToken($token);
}

// Manually refresh to be able to reformat before use
if (array_key_exists("expires_in", $token) && $token["created"] +     $token["expires_in"] < time() + 20) {
$client->refreshToken($token["refresh_token"]);
    $client->setToken(reformatToken($client->getToken()));
}

// After authenticate/refresh, save valid token to database, only if it's a new token
if (!$token || $token["created"] < $client->getToken()["created"]) {
$query = $db->getQuery(true);
$fields = array($db->quoteName("profile_value") . " = " . $db->quote(json_encode($client->getToken())));
$query->update($db->quoteName("#__user_profiles"))->set($fields)->where($dbTokenConditions);
$db->setQuery($query)->execute();
}

/*
 * The script to get the engagement:
 */

// GET all the calendars from timetag.
$organizations = $client->query("https://timetag.it/api/v1.0.1/organizations");
$organizations = json_decode($organizations->body, true);

$name = str_replace(' ', '', JFactory::getUser()->username);
$format = "Y-m-d\TH:i:s"; // RFC3339
// First day of this month
$min_time = date($format, strtotime("first day of " . date("M")));
$max_time = date($format, strtotime("first day of next month " . date("M")));
// First day of this year
$min_time_year = date($format, strtotime("first day of January " . date("Y")));
$hoursSpendThisMonth = $hoursSpendThisYear = 0;

// Iterate over each calendar
foreach ($organizations as $organization => $datavalues) {

$organizationId = $datavalues["id"];
$projects = $client->query("https://timetag.it/api/v1.0.1/projects?organization_id=" . $organizationId);
$projects = json_decode($projects->body, true);

    // Iterate over each event that belongs to the logged in user (project)
    foreach ($projects as $project => $values) {
    if ($values["name"] === $name) {
        $projectId = $values["id"];
        $monthdata = $client->query("https://timetag.it/api/v1.0.1/projects/" . $projectId . "/hours_spent?organization_id=" . $organizationId . "&min_time=" . $min_time . "&max_time=" . $max_time);
        $hoursSpendThisMonth += json_decode($monthdata->body, true)["hours_spent"];

        $yeardata = $client->query("https://timetag.it/api/v1.0.1/projects/" . $projectId . "/hours_spent?organization_id=" . $organizationId . "&min_time=" . $min_time_year);
        $hoursSpendThisYear += json_decode($yeardata->body, true)["hours_spent"];
    }
}
}

// Convert base 100 to minutes(base 60).
$timeSpendThisMonth['hours'] = floor($hoursSpendThisMonth);
$timeSpendThisMonth['minutes'] = $hoursSpendThisMonth - $timeSpendThisMonth['hours'];
$timeSpendThisMonth['minutes'] = round($timeSpendThisMonth['minutes'] * 60);
$timeSpendThisYear['hours'] = floor($hoursSpendThisYear);
$timeSpendThisYear['minutes'] = $hoursSpendThisYear - $timeSpendThisYear['hours'];
$timeSpendThisYear['minutes'] = round($timeSpendThisYear['minutes'] * 60);

// Redirect if authentication code is still in the URL
if (isset($_GET["code"]))
JFactory::getApplication()->redirect(JURI::current());

// Get the hours value from JomSocial
$engagedMonthly = CFactory::getUser()->getInfo("FIELD_HOURS") ? : 192 / 12;
?>

<input id="firstTab" type="radio" name="tabs" checked>
<label for="firstTab">Maand</label>

<input id="secondTab" type="radio" name="tabs">
<label for="secondTab">Jaar</label>

<div class="content">
<div class="monthlyEngagement">
    <span class="workedHours"><? echo $timeSpendThisMonth['hours'] ?>u <?     echo $timeSpendThisMonth['minutes'] ?>m</span>/<? echo $engagedMonthly ?>u deze maand
    <br>
    <div class="progressBar">
        <div class="percentage" style="width:<? echo $hoursSpendThisMonth > $engagedMonthly ? 250 : $hoursSpendThisMonth/$engagedMonthly*250 ?>px"></div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="yearlyEngagement">
    <span class="workedHours"><? echo $timeSpendThisYear['hours'] ?>u <? echo $timeSpendThisYear['minutes'] ?>m</span> gewerkt in <? echo date("Y") ?>
</div>
</div>
```